# InnerHTML cannot find the ID

Tags: jquery, innerhtml

It works in JSFiddle but in my code an innerHTML call won't work, as it seems it cannot find the ID specified. But I can clearly see it on the page.

The code is for a countdown timer. Here is the code:

```
<script>
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date("Aug 15, 2019").getTime();

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdownOpening = document.getElementById("countdownOpening");

// update the tag with id "countdownOpening" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

    // do some time calculations
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

    // format countdown string + set tag value
    countdownOpening.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "
    + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";  

}, 1000);
</script>
```

The error in the console doesn't seem to appear until when the .innerHTML is called so I think the rest is working OK.

```
countdownOpening.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "
        + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";
```

Here is the ID which is on the page:

```
<span id="countdownOpening"></span>
```

I can't understand why it's having issues with finding that element.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null index.html:39
(anonymous function)
```

And the error counts every second so I think it's working in terms of the countdown but just unable to update the span.

[Live link](http://www.francesca-designed.me/fyp/): username is admin password is gogogo

Comment: Add `console.log(countdownOpening);` to your setInterval it looks like you don't have the variable for some reason inside your setInterval so it has to be getting removed or unset or something somewhere else.

Comment: @Steven I tried console and got nothing. Tried an alert and it pulls back null. But the var should be global?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have initialized you script before the DOM has had a chance to load the content.
So when you are declaring 'var countdownOpening = document.getElementById("countdownOpening");' it's not actually on the page yet, so it can't find the control to set the variable.

You should move your script to the foot of the page, so that the content has loaded.

Alteratively, since you are using JQuery, you could initialize the variable inside the document ready function:

```
var countdownOpening;

$(document).ready(function(){ countdownOpening = document.getElementById("countdownOpening"); })
```

Comment: Just a little note, if you are using jQuery, you should try and use as much of it as possible (ie `countdownOpening = $('#countdownOpening');`) if you only use jQuery for document.ready find something else to do domReady ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed to put *document.getElementById("countdownOpening")* incide the function? I mean where you have *countdownOpening.innerHTML = ...*

Comment: Is it not better to define a variable instead and use that?

Comment: Just tried it and it doesn't work. Also tried using an alert in the setInterval function to pull back countdownOpening and get null

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the id before you call the javascript function for that ID. Create the span with the id 'countdownOpening'. Below that you call the function. It should work.

Like the below one

`<span id="countdownOpening"></span>`

```
<script>
    //call the function here
</script>
```